# How to dynamically set the connection property of a model in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel 5.1 App and I can dynamically set the connection property of a model doing this:

```
class Config extends Model {

public function __construct() {
    $this->connection = Session::get('conn') or abort(500, 'No conn');
}

protected $table = 'config';
}
```

But in Laravel 5.3+ we are not able to access the session in constructors methods without having to `hack` the framework.

What is the best/recommended way to do this on a model?

**UPDATE:**
This code actually works, my problem was at the Controller level not the Model.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It works perfectly for me? I'm able to call session inside constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works perfectly.

**Using facade**

Import

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

and then you can call like

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->connection = Session::get('conn') or abort(500, 'No conn');
}
```

**Using helper function**

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->connection = session('conn') or abort(500, 'No conn');
}
```

Comment: Yes! my bad, I was having the problem in the Controller not in the Model.

Answer (score 1):

Use the global session helper

```
 $this->connection = session('conn') or abort(500, 'No conn');
```